# vertical katakana (with uplatex)

Tags: cjk, japanese, uplatex

Let's assume we have a simple `«hello world»` in Japanese (/sue:den/ — that's Sweden in Japanese):

```
\documentclass{utarticle}
\begin{document}
スウェーデン。
\end{document}
```

The `utarticle` class tells the LaTeX to render it vertically, and so far it's just as expected. But here comes the issue (actually, even three of them):

1. The long vowel sign `(ー)` in the vertical layout also must be vertical. But it isn't.
2. The small `«e»` `(エ)` must be shifted to the right edge of the column. But it isn't.
3. The full stop `(。)` must be also adjusted by the right edge of the column. But it isn't.

A picture of the real output vs. desired result: [image: png]

Platform — Linux, Fedora 24.

How to get it working? (solved)

```
 *File List*
 upldefs.ltx    2000/07/13 v1.2u01 upLaTeX Kernel (Default settings)
 jy2mc.fd    1997/01/24 v1.3 KANJI font defines
 jy2gt.fd    1997/01/24 v1.3 KANJI font defines
 jt2mc.fd    1997/01/24 v1.3 KANJI font defines
 jt2gt.fd    1997/01/24 v1.3 KANJI font defines
 ukinsoku.tex
 uplpatch.ltx
 utarticle.cls    2011/05/07 v1.6_u00 Standard upLaTeX class
 utsize10.clo    2011/05/07 v1.6_u00 Standard upLaTeX file (size option)
 plext.sty    
 ***********
```

**Solution**

Thanks to @JosephWright : do not use LaTeX provided by Fedora's packages, instead install the fresh LaTeX from the site.

[image: png]

After the upgrade:

```
 *File List*
 upldefs.ltx    2016/06/29 v1.6e-u00 upLaTeX Kernel (Default settings)
 jy2mc.fd    1997/01/24 v1.3 KANJI font defines
 jy2gt.fd    1997/01/24 v1.3 KANJI font defines
 jt2mc.fd    1997/01/24 v1.3 KANJI font defines
 jt2gt.fd    1997/01/24 v1.3 KANJI font defines
 ukinsoku.tex
 utarticle.cls    2011/05/07 v1.6-u00 Standard upLaTeX class
 utsize10.clo    2011/05/07 v1.6-u00 Standard upLaTeX file (size option)
 plext.sty    2016/08/20 v1.2a pLaTeX package file (community edition)
 ***********
```

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of what you see to make it clear to others?

Comment: are you using the `cjk`-package,  which provides support for Asian languages? see also: https://www.preining.info/blog/2014/12/writing-japanese-in-latex-part-1-introduction/

Comment: @naphaneal pLaTeX is a 'self-contained' environment for Japanese wrok: it uses a special engine, pTeX/upTeX.

Comment: If I run `ptex2pdf -u -l test` (I saved your example as `test.tex`) gives [this picture (click here)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pu8ZD.png)

Comment: @egreg , your picture is just perfect, but I get the same as above :| As I told, it looks like I'm missing something too obvious

Comment: I get the same as @egreg doing `uplatex test && dvipdfmx test` with TeX Live 2016, up-to-date on Windows. Can you add `\listfiles` to your input and edit the `File list` from the `.log` into the question?

Comment: There is no `ヨ` in `スウェーデン`, did you mean the small `ェ`?

Comment: @JosephWright , yep, I'll do that now. I believe, the keyword here is «Windows», but in my case Windows is not an option. But it's good to know that on Windows it is working — maybe I have to file a bug onto the Fedora's bugzilla.

Comment: @Alenanno , yep, pardonnez-moi, mea culpa.

Comment: Eeek, your system is _old_. I have `upldefs.ltx    2016/06/29 v1.6e-u00`. My guess is that is where the issue is. BTW, @egreg is a Mac user: this is not platform-specific.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was due to outdated software, solved by an upgrade.

Comment: @egreg Unfortunately, this outdated software is a part of one of the latest major Linux distros (Fedora24, just released). Being a newbie, it's not so easy to understand the source of the issue, and it hard to discover via google — it looks like all the folk believes that this question is offtopic.

Comment: @svinota We usually recommend installing the “vanilla” TeX Live, just because the one provided by major GNU/Linux distributions often lags behind.

Comment: @egreg , yep. You're right, after all it's not a TeX issue.

Comment: The difference between the first one (wrong output) and the second one (current one; "solution") lies in Japanese font. Only a guess, but:
In the wrong output, svinota didn't embed any physical font (actually TeX Live 2015 or earlier does NOT embed Japanese fonts by default). In this case, the characters had to be substituted by some system font (maybe without vertical glyphs) to be displayed on the pdf viewer. TeX Live 2016 embeds "IPAex font" by default, and it contains vertical glyphs. So, font substitution for display does not happen. That's all, I think.

Comment: I mean, the problem lies in the **usage** of dvipdfmx; command `uplatex test.tex && dvipdfmx -f uptex-ipaex.map test.dvi` can embed IPAex font even with the old system. This is the **right** solution for this question from Japan. (TeX Live 2016 does the similar thing by default using updmap, but 2015 or earlier does not.)